# Fade with a DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, dispatchertimer

In my `uwp` project i have 3 different color overlays on pictures (Green, yellow and red). These colors are supposed to indicate if a Room (In this case the room is a picture) is booked or not.

If the room is booked it should fade out the `green color` and fade over the `red color`, and then after 7 seconds the `red color` should fade over to `yellow color`, and then finally the `yellow color` should fade over to `green color` again.

1. For the fade i´m using `Windows Animation extension for UWP`.
2. `Green Color` is set as default.

Right now when a room is booked the the first fade is working (Red to yellow), but there is no fade for `Yellow` to `Green`.

```
    public void RedIndicatorColorToYellowIndicatorColor()
    {
        StatusColor.Fade(duration: 1000, delay: 2000, value: 0).Start();
        StatusColor.Fill = RedBrush;
        DispatcherTimer ColorTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        ColorTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7);
        ColorTimer.Tick += (Sender, args) =>
        {
            YellowindIcatorColorToGreenIndicatorColor();
            ColorTimer.Stop();
        };
        ColorTimer.Start();
    }

    public void YellowindIcatorColorToGreenIndicatorColor()
    {
        StatusColor.Fade(duration: 1000, delay: 0, value: 1).Start();
        StatusColor.Fill = YellowBrush;
        DispatcherTimer ColorTimer2 = new DispatcherTimer();
        ColorTimer2.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7);
        ColorTimer2.Tick += (Zender, Args) =>
        {
            StatusColor.Fill = GreenBrush;
            ColorTimer2.Stop();
        };
        ColorTimer2.Start();
    }
```

`StatusColor` is the Rectangle that holds the color overlays.

Comment: Your above code works well in my side using the [Fade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/animations/Fade). It fades from Red to Yellow then from Yellow to Green. What is your xaml code? I can not reproduce your issue, could you provide a minum sample to help me see it?

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT Thanks for the answer! I have solved the problem already, but i forgot to remove the question... But thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: Okay, glad to here that :).

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT Thanks! I suould remove the question right? :)

Comment: You might want to switch to using a color animation/storyboard instead. That takes away the timer code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ***Solved the problem!***

```
public void RedIndicatorColorToYellowIndicatorColor()
            {
                StatusColor.Fill = GreenBrush;
                DispatcherTimer ColorTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
                ColorTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7);
                ColorTimer.Tick += async (Sender, args) =>
                {
                    await StatusColor.Fade(duration: 1000, delay: 0, value: 0).StartAsync();
                    StatusColor.Fill = RedBrush;
                    await StatusColor.Fade(duration: 1200, delay: 0, value: 1).StartAsync();

                    YellowindIcatorColorToGreenIndicatorColor();
                    ColorTimer.Stop();
                };
                ColorTimer.Start();
            }

            public void YellowindIcatorColorToGreenIndicatorColor()
            {
                DispatcherTimer ColorTimer2 = new DispatcherTimer();
                ColorTimer2.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7);
                ColorTimer2.Tick += async (Zender, Args) =>
                {
                    await StatusColor.Fade(duration: 1000, delay: 0, value: 0).StartAsync();
                    StatusColor.Fill = YellowBrush;
                    await StatusColor.Fade(duration: 1200, delay: 0, value: 1).StartAsync();

                    red2green();
                    ColorTimer2.Stop();
                };
                ColorTimer2.Start();
            }
```